# Add criterias to exclude some records from the Salesforce global search

Tags: contact, search, global-search

Is there a way to add criterias from the global Salesforce search to hide some records in the result?
Contacts are public and reachable from accounts but some contacts don't have to found with a search.

I would like to exclude contacts with a specific value in a field (or maybe using a record type to exclude).

Thanks